# Regular Expressions in R - exclude keyword

Tags: regex, r

There are two variables in my data set with similar names: "JE.Description" and "Field.Description". How can I target the column index of the "JE.Description" column, so as to exclude the word "Field" from the RegExp search? In other words, I would like to modify the command below to only returns the column index of "JE.Description":

The data set is frequently updated and sometimes the "JE.Description" string is shown just as "Description". That is why I am seeking a solution to explicitly excluded the keyword "Field".

```
r1 <- c(1:5)
r2 <- c(1:5)
df <- data.frame(r1,r2)
names(df)[1] <- "JE.Description"
names(df)[2] <- "Field.Description"

y <- grep("!^Field^Description",perl = TRUE, colnames(df))
RETURNS: integer[0]
```

Thanks,

Comment: Could you make a quick example of strings that should and shouldn't be matched (perhaps some of your colnames)?

Comment: It looks like your pattern works exactly as you want it to. `x <- c("Description", "Field.Description"); grep("^Description$",perl=TRUE, x)` results in `[1] 1`

Comment: @ndoogan yes, you're right. But I am trying to find a way to explicitly exclude "field" from the regex search. Sometimes the data set shows, "Description" (in which case the command in question works), and other times it shows "JE.Description". Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To match every string containing `"Description"` **except** for those in which it's immediately preceded by the `"Field."`, use a negative lookbehind assertion:

```
## The regex pattern
pat <- "(?<!Field\\.)Description"

## Try it out
x <- c("Description", "Field.Description", "FieldDescription", "xyz Description")
grep(pat, x, perl=TRUE)  # Note: lookahead & lookbehind assertions need perl=TRUE
# [1] 1 3 4
```

Alternatively, if the substring `"field"` might occur in some other position relative to `"Description"`, (and perhaps in either upper or lower-case version) it might be simpler to just `grepl()` twice and use Boolean operators to combine the results:

```
x <- c("Description", "fieldDescription", "Field-of-Description", 
       "Description field")
which(grepl("Description", x) & !grepl("field", x, ignore.case=TRUE))
[1] 1
```

Comment: @agstudy -- Only b/c, after originally posting it, I reread the question and saw that, on its face, it was asking for something different. (Now, after several more edits, I see that my original guess may have been correct ... and just now, it's been confirmed by the OP.)

Answer (score 0):

```
mydata<-structure(list(Description = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 
14.3, 24.4, 22.8, 19.2), Field.Description = c(6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 
6, 8, 4, 4, 6)), .Names = c("Description", "Field.Description"
), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", 
"Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant", "Duster 360", 
"Merc 240D", "Merc 230", "Merc 280"), class = "data.frame")

mydata[grep("^Description",names(mydata))]
                  Description
Mazda RX4                21.0
Mazda RX4 Wag            21.0
Datsun 710               22.8
Hornet 4 Drive           21.4
Hornet Sportabout        18.7
Valiant                  18.1
Duster 360               14.3
Merc 240D                24.4
Merc 230                 22.8
Merc 280                 19.2
```