# Regular Expression: Exclude keywords from Email R

Tags: r, string

I have a text field that has email addresses for which I made below pattern

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(Data, "([a-zA-Z0-9.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9.-])")
```

It works perfect and detects everything. However, I need to exclude emails from certain domains like gmail.com. For instance, I don't want emails that are with `@gmail.com`.

Using not symbol (`^`), I should be able to achieve my need, however, I have no idea why I get stock after several trial of adding `^gmail.com` to my pattern.

Comment: Please add a `library(myfavpackage)` line ahead of your code for relevant packages. Anyway, I think the best/cleanest way is to use your pattern and then filter the results after-the-fact. Instead of hard-coding `^gmail.com` or similar, keep a vector of blacklisted domains, `c("gmail.com","yahoo.com",...)`.

Comment: It is a valid solution, however, I thought it is not an efficient way. First I have to create a big list of emails and then start removing them again. This will become harder as number of emails is high in each record (sometimes 100 emails in one record)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple obvious ways to go, starting from...

```
x       = c("Espanta@gmail.com","Frank@notgmail.com","Jaap@gmail.com.com")
baddoms = c("gmail.com","yahoo.com")
```

filter first...

```
str_split_fixed(x[grep(paste0("@(",paste(baddoms,collapse="|"),")$"), x, invert=TRUE)], "@", 2)
#      [,1]    [,2]           
# [1,] "Frank" "notgmail.com" 
# [2,] "Jaap"  "gmail.com.com"
```

... or filter afterwards ...

```
y = str_split_fixed(x, "@", 2)
y[!(y[,2] %in% baddoms),]
#      [,1]    [,2]           
# [1,] "Frank" "notgmail.com" 
# [2,] "Jaap"  "gmail.com.com"
```

As far as code complexity and computational time goes, the second approach is much better. One could argue that the first means saving RAM, but I really doubt that would be a problem in practice.

---

The OP's idea of using `^gmail.com` does not work because `^` has two uses in regex:

- identifying the start of the string; and
- negating characters inside a character class `[^...]`.

To dodge entire strings, [negative lookaheads and lookbehinds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19368482/1191259) are handy, but I know of no way to (1) extract parts from a string and (2) filter results in a single step.